# Education and Experience are not in Syn for Germany Job seeker visa

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, immigration, job-hunting

I have a chemical Engineering degree and I am working in IT as a programmer Analyst since 7 years on H1B in USA (Indian National).

Do I qualify for Germany Job Seeker Visa?

Is there any chance for denial because my education is not relevant to my work experience?

Answer (score 1):

For the German Blue Card you need **either**

- a job offer in the field of your university degree

or

- a job offer in a field you have at least 5 years experience in

Not necessarily both. See [§ 19a AufenthG, Abs. 1.1a, relevant the last word: **oder** ("or")](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/aufenthg_2004/__19a.html)